# Power Pivot Row Heirarchys in pivot table with own dimension having its own totals

Tags: pivot-table, data-modeling, dax, powerpivot, measure

I have a data in the data model based on a product hierarchy. The hierarchy is

1.Type

2.Product Type

3.Product Group

The Measure I have for this is % of total revenue.

Here is a simplified example of the table

[image: Food Pivot]

In this Pivot, is is broken down by type, product type, and product group. I want the column to show what % the revenue is for each specific group and subgroup in one column. For example the Grocery row should be what % the grocery revenue is of the total company. The Food row should show what % the food revenue is of all the product groups. Then the meat and supplies should show what % total they are of each of their own groups. Basically the % dont roll up to one number due to different factors, but rather each group has its own specific total

I have a single data table that has the total revenues for each of these groups in the data model, but i am having trouble figuring out how to have each specific row show what i want. I can link one, but then all the rows show % related to that link and not how I want it broken down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Power Pivot- Sum based on rows in actual pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162548/power-pivot-sum-based-on-rows-in-actual-pivot-table)

Comment: The other has more context and images

Comment: I understand that you posted an improved version of this question. But please remove the older version, as it is essentially a duplicate.